# Running command periodically and save output to a CSV file

Tags: command-line, python

I am running some command in an SDN emulator. 
The command is:

```
$ py ap1.params['frequency']
```

It gives me a single value (float) output. How can I write a small python script or using a single command to run the above command after every 2 seconds and append each output to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

*<sup>Disclaimer: I don't know a thing about python, I just combine what's said in the below given sources. I'm not able to test it and there is a change that this is terribly wrong.</sup>*

1. Write a while loop with a sleep command that regularly calls your command: <sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926328/efficient-and-fast-python-while-loop-while-using-sleep)</sup>

   ```
   import time; while True: ap1.params['frequency']; time.sleep(2)
   ```

   This will in fact *not* call the command every two seconds but rather wait  two seconds between every run – you might want to tweak the sleep time.
2. Run the loop and redirect the output to a file appending it: <sup>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)</sup>

   ```
   py 'import time; while True: ap1.params['frequency']; time.sleep(2)' >> output.csv
   ```

   There are other ways to redirect the output, of course python itself is also totally capable of doing this – see the source for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can (sort of mis-)use the `watch` command:

```
watch -n 2 -p "( py ap1.params[\'frequency\'] >>output.csv )"
```

You won't see much on the screen that watch will show except for the time changing, because the actual output is redirected.
Note the command given to watch including the redirection needs to be grouped in parentheses. ALso, with or without *watch*, probably the single quotes in the command (`'frequency'`) should be escaped with \ so they are not stripped by the shell.

See `man watch` for more info.